# complex regex on custom string tags

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I'm trying to get text between tags made in square brackets.

Let see the simple string example:

*[french]This is a French text[/french][english]This is a English text[/english]*

And then in PHP (using https://stackoverflow.com/a/9826656/962734) :

```
private function translate($string)
{
    $start = "[".$this->lang."]";
    $end = "[/".$this->lang."]";
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return $string;
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
```

How about more complex solution?

I mean if the language is not set -> use default (english). If string contains string outside tags display it along selected language. If string not contains language that is requested -> display default (or if the default is not set, display first  found in the string. Examples:

```
$this->language->__set("defLang", "english");

$str = "This is a [french]French text[/french][english]English text[/english]";
$this->language->lang = "french"; 
return $this->language->translate($str);
//OUTPUT: This is a French text

$str = "This is a [deutch]Deutch text[/deutch][english]English text[/english]";
$this->language->lang = "french"; 
return $this->language->translate($str);
//OUTPUT: This is a English text

$str = "This is a [french]French text[/french][deutch]Deutch text[/deutch]";
$this->language->lang = "english"; 
return $this->language->translate($str);
//OUTPUT: This is a French text
```

What is the best way to do this using PHP? I suspect that it will require complex regex, but as I'm not familiar with regex, I'd like to know if there's other way.

**EDIT:**

Based on answer provided by jeff (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17727494/962734), I made the function that works in most cases. Thanks.

```
function translate($text)
{
    $exp = '/(\[(.+?)\])(.+?)\[\/.+?\]/i';
    $m = preg_match_all( $exp, $text, $matches);

    if($m){

        $mtchs = $matches[0];
        $langs = $matches[2];
        $texts = $matches[3];
        $c = 0;
        $foundLang = false;
        $foundFirstOptionalLang = false;

        foreach($langs as $l){
            if($l == $this->lang){
                $text = str_replace($mtchs[$c], $texts[$c], $text);
                $foundLang = true;
            }else{
                if(!$foundFirstOptionalLang && $l == $this->defLang){
                    $optionalText = str_replace($mtchs[$c], $texts[$c], $text);
                    $foundFirstOptionalLang = true;
                }
                $text = str_replace($mtchs[$c], "", $text);
            }
            $c++;
        }
        if (!$foundLang) $text = $optionalText;
    }

    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Is that the only possible format of the text? Will they always be next to each other and only one set in a string?

Comment: Not really. These are only examples of how the string may looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
$exp = '/(\[(.+?)\])(.+?)\[\/.+?\]/i';
$str = "This is a [french]French text[/french] and [english]English text[/english]";

$m = preg_match_all( $exp, $str, $matches);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump( $matches);
echo "</pre>";
```

This will return

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>string(28) "[french]French text[/french]"
    [1]=>string(31) "[english]English text[/english]"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=> string(8) "[french]"
    [1]=> string(9) "[english]"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>string(6) "french"
    [1]=>string(7) "english"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>string(11) "French text"
    [1]=>string(12) "English text"
  }
}
```

So you would access array[2] for the language name and array[3] for the actual text.

Comment: I can accept this as it's good and clear base for later work on. I've updated my question, added working function in most cases, based on your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular situation:

```
function getTextInTag($text,$tag='english')
{
    $innerText = preg_replace('#^.*\['.$tag.'\](.+?)\[/'.$tag.'\].*$#','$1',$text);
    if($innerText == $text) $innerText = preg_replace('#^.*\[english\](.+?)\[/english\].*$#','$1',$text);
    $text = preg_replace('#(\[[^\]]+\].+?\[/[^\]]+\])+#','',$text);
    return $text.$innerText;
}

getTextInTag('This is a [french]French text[/french][english]English text[/english]'); //This is a English text
getTextInTag('This is a [french]French text[/french][english]English text[/english]','french'); //This is a French text
getTextInTag('This is a [french]French text[/french][english]English text[/english]','spanish'); //This is a English text
```

Comment: Yes. Upvoted because for my examples it does the trick. But it's still not really complex solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function translate($str){
      // If the language has been set use it, otherwise use the default value         
      $lang = isset($this->language->lang)?$this->language->lang:$this->language->defLang;

      if(preg_match("/\[$lang\](.+)\[\/$lang\]/", $str, $m)){
           return $m[1];              
      }else{
           // There was no text found for $lang,  fall back to english         
           preg_match("/\[english\](.+)\[\/english\]/", $str, $m);
           return $m[1];
      }


 }
```

Comment: This is basic static solution. Not really complex as it works the same way as in my first example without regex. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why you want to make it "complex" if it works.  What more does it need to do that you haven't explained?

Comment: it doesn't check whether any lang is set in the string. 2. Doesn't check neither if default language is set in the string. It doesn't accept the string outside tags... More than "working" solution for a particular example I'd like to have universal solution to make it works in most cases. Thanks.