# get substring between the "bread" string

Tags: php

I have an array :

```
    $testcase = array(
    array('breadjambread', "jam"),
    array('breadjammbread', "jam"),
    array('xxbreadjambreadyy', "jam"),
    array('xxbreadyy', ""),
    array('xxbreadbreadjambreadyy', "breadjamm"),
    array('breadAbread', "A"),
    array('breadbread', ""),
    array('abcbreaz', ""),
    array('xyz', ""),
    array('', ""),
    array('breadbreaxbread', "breax"),
    array('breaxbreadybread', "y"),
    array('breadbreadbreadbread', "breadbread"),
    array('breadbread5breadbread', "breadbread"),
    array('breadbreadbreadbread', "bread5bread"),
);
```

I want to get the substring between the "bread".

```
Ex: array[0][0]="breadjambread and I will get the "jam"

    array[1][0]="breadjammbread", I will get the "jamm"

    array[2][0]="xxbreadjambreadyy", the result will be "jam"
```

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get substring between two strings PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/get-substring-between-two-strings-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a regular expression you can match a string that is surrounded by other strings:

```
preg_match('/(?<=bread).+?(?=bread)/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

The `.+?` is what you are trying to match, `(?<=bread)` means that it should have "bread" in-front of it and `(?=bread)` means that it should have "bread" behind it.

You can also use the `strpos()` and `substr()` functions to find a string in-between two other strings, but it would require some trial and error on your part.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

```
if (preg_match('/bread(.*?)bread/', $string, $match)) {
    $word_between_bread = $match[1];
}
```