# Php get string between tags

Tags: php, regex

I got a string like this which is (Joomla all video plugin)

```
{Vimeo}123456789{/Vimeo}
```

where 123456789 is variable, how can I extract this?
Should I use regex?

Comment: Yep, regex will do this. Try here: http://regex101.com.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/get-substring-between-two-strings-php

Comment: Righto, three people upvoted this? By which they assert that: "This question shows research effort, it is useful and clear"? (see the hover-over text).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you must use a regular expression, the following will do the trick.

```
$str = 'foo {Vimeo}123456789{/Vimeo} bar';
preg_match('~{Vimeo}([^{]*){/Vimeo}~i', $str, $match);
var_dump($match[1]); // string(9) "123456789"
```

This may be more than what you want to go through, but here is a way to avoid regex.

```
$str = 'foo {Vimeo}123456789{/Vimeo} bar';
$m = substr($str, strpos($str, '{Vimeo}')+7);
$m = substr($m, 0, strpos($m, '{/Vimeo}'));
var_dump($m); // string(9) "123456789"
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's another solution for you

```
$str = "{Vimeo}123456789{/Vimeo}";

preg_match("/\{(\w+)\}(.+?)\{\/\\1\}/", $str, $matches);

printf("tag: %s, body: %s", $matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Output

```
tag: Vimeo, body: 123456789
```

---

Or you could build it into a function like this

```
function getTagValues($tag, $str) {
    $re = sprintf("/\{(%s)\}(.+?)\{\/\\1\}/", preg_quote($tag));
    preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
    return $matches[2];
}

$str = "{Vimeo}123456789{/Vimeo} and {Vimeo}123{/Vimeo}";

var_dump(getTagValues("Vimeo", $str));
```

Output

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "123456789"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "123"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may try like this:

```
$string = '{Vimeo}123456789{/Vimeo} ';

echo extractString($string, '{Vimeo}', '{/Vimeo}');

function extractString($string, $start, $end) {
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could use regex.Like this:

```
preg_match_all('/{Vimeo}(.*?){\/Vimeo}/s', $yourstring, $matches);
```

Comment: Your middle forward slash will need escaping. On a wider note, no effort has been expended by the OP, and it may not be doing the community a favour by answering these sorts of questions.

Comment: @derdida Thank you very much! None of the above examples worked for my scenario, but yours did. Don't listen to halfer, keep on posting to questions if you have other ways of going about a problem

Answer (score 1):

If the buildup is always like that you could also replace the tags by nothing

```
$string = '{Vimeo}123456789{/Vimeo}';
str_replace(array('{Vimeo}', '{/Vimeo}'), '', $string);
```