# Array and substring php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, substring

```
     //array data                          
   {
    $results[] = $result;

    $SiteID=$result["site_id"];
    $pay_sale_id=$result["pay_sale_id"];
    $pay_payment_info=$result["pay_payment_info"];
    $payNo= substring_index(substring_index('$result["pay_payment_info"]', '$USER=', -1), '~$TAGROLE', 1);

 }
```

The  content of pay_payment_info is as follows

```
#$TAG=6F0000173~$USER=james~$TAGROLE=0
```

I want to extract only the user info, but i get error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function substring_index() in line

Comment: have you defined function substring_index

Comment: There is no `substring_index()` function in PHP.

Comment: Try this [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: You are mixing MySQL code with PHP code... those are totally different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the user info always begins with `~$USER=` and ends with a `~` we can get the result using simple regex:

```
preg_match('/\~\$USER=(?<user>[^~]+)/', $pay_payment_info, $match);
var_dump($match['user']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you exactly why it is an error: `substring_index` is not a valid/native PHP function... you can define your own function of `substring_index`, though.

However, given the string:

> $TAG=6F0000173~$USER=james~$TAGROLE=0

to get the **$USER=james** part, you can use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) as follows--

```
$payNo = explode("~", $result["pay_payment_info"])
```

Now, you have the `$USER` info in `$payNo[1]`

If you want to go even further and *just* get the value of what `$USER` value is, then you can use PHP's native [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function:

```
$justUserPart = substr($payNo[1], strpos($payNo[1], "=")+1);
echo $justUserPart;
```

*Please Note*: The above assumes that you will *always* have the string in the format of

> $TAG=**...**~$USER=**...**~$TAGROLE=**...**

Answer (score 0):

As previous comments said - there is no such function like `substring_index` in core PHP

This question is possible duplicate of following [Php get string between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817248/php-get-string-between-tags)
topic

Here is working example with usage of `strpos` http://php.net/manual/pl/function.strpos.php

and `substr` http://php.net/manual/pl/function.substr.php

```
$var = '$TAG=6F0000173~$USER=james~$TAGROLE=0';
$m = substr($var, strpos($var, '~$USER=')+7);
var_dump($m); //returns string(16) "james~$TAGROLE=0"
$m = substr($m, 0, strpos($m, '~$'));
var_dump($m); //returns string(5) "james"
```

Comment: Note: the above will fail, if OP decides to name `$USER` to say, `$USERINFO` or `$USERNAME` etc. (i.e. anything >7 chars)

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the problem is you have no `substring_index()` function or method, yet you attempt to invoke it twice.

I am not sure why you use the `~` as a delimiter but that should be ok, although using a `,` would have resulted in less work; each of the attributes of your querystring would have been able to be addressed directly then.

what you want to do is use the `php` version of `split()` which is `explode()`  here is a [link to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

what you want to do is split the inc string:

```
$aUserInfo = explode('~', $result['pay_payment_info']);
```

now you have an array.  loop through it and make it like you want:

```
$result = array();
foreach($aUserInfo as $v){
  $aTmp = explode('=',$v);
  $result[$aTmp[0]] = $aTmp[1];
}
```

at the end of this you have an array with keys as keys and their respective values as values, i.e.

```
$result = array( 'tag' => '6F0000173',
                 'user'=> 'James',
                 'tagrole'=> 0    );
```

Comment: how about if use substring in sql like this   $sql="INSERT INTO `payments_data`(`site_id`, `Pay_sale_id`, `Pay_paymnet_type`, `Pay_payment_info`)
    VALUES ('00','0','0',    substring_index(substring_index('$pay_payment_info', '$USER=', -1), '~$TAGROLE', 1)
    )";

Comment: what is this `substring_index()` you keep wanting to invoke?  it is not a built in function.  I am not sure if you are attempting to concatenate a string and store it, but that seems the most likely.  ...  you should restructure your data, but if that isnt possible, spit the string into there, leave out that other method, or let me know what it is supposed to do and I can likely emulate it

Comment: I am trying to store only a portion of data, I want to extract user name and store it in a database

Comment: ahh ok, `$result["user"]` should be that value