# Generating personal mail

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a function in admin panel of my project, that will be sending e-mails with some dynamic parameters in format `*|folder:function|*`. E.g.:
I write in text form

```
Hello, *|USER:FIRSTNAME|*. 
You can *|START-LINKS:ACTIVATE|*activate*|END-LINKS|* your account. 
Also you can *|START-LINKS:UNSUBSCRIBE|*unsubscribe*|END-LINKS|*.
```

and want to get

```
Hello, John.
You can <a href="http://example.com/?do=activate&user_id=useridfromdatabase&unique=4se5dr6ftygyuertcfvgbh">activate</a> your account.
Also you can <a href="http://example.com/?do=unsubscribe&user_id=useridfromdatabase&unique=45r6ftetdf3445656576yt">unsubscribe</a>
```

But I don't know how I can replace my tags with the data that I needed. Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: Use [str_replace()](http://nl3.php.net/str_replace) or search for any other useful [string function](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)

Comment: I tried it and nothing get. Can you give an example?

Comment: Either simply replace in the string or use regular expression http://fr2.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=replace&scope=quickref

Comment: @KirillDanshin Can you show us how you've done it?

Comment: @AMS but how? I really don't know

Comment: You've been unable to replace `*|USER:FIRSTNAME|*` with `John` using `str_replace()`? May we see your failed attempt?

Comment: @Kirill Danshin go on php.net and read the documentation maybe this could be a good start

Comment: @h2ooooooo no, I deleted this function already

Comment: @KirillDanshin If you don't want to show us what you've tried, you shouldn't post on stack overflow. We're not a "give me teh codez" site. If you want someone else to make your code, you can [**hire a paid freelancer**](http://www.freelancer.com). You can also read [**How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @h2ooooooo I found my fail: I add \ in *| (result - *\|), and I was think, that it's ok.

Comment: @KirillDanshin Are you using `str_replace` or `preg_replace`? The latter is for **regex** and not strings. If you just want to change an exact string, use `str_replace`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo str_replace. No, I changing string, and then I want to send it with PHPMailer

Comment: @KirillDanshin [I cannot confirm that you need to escape the '\' ?](https://eval.in/197372)

Comment: @h2ooooooo sorry, I don't understand your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like

```
$email_body = str_replace("*|USER:FIRSTNAME|*, $users_name, $email_body");
```

If you can help it, don't try and be too clever, because when it breaks in two years time, you'll have no idea how to fix it quickly.

If you insist on doing it slightly more cleverly, use [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/get-substring-between-two-strings-php) to get the data between your beginning and end characters and explode() the contents by the : character.

Answer (score 0):

```
$bodytag = str_replace("*|USER:FIRSTNAME|*", "John", "Hello, *|USER:FIRSTNAME|*. 
You can *|START-LINKS:ACTIVATE|*activate*|END-LINKS|* your account. 
Also you can *|START-LINKS:UNSUBSCRIBE|*unsubscribe*|END-LINKS|*.");
```

This is what you ask for but you have many possibilities str_replace, regular expression or sprintf

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php
https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=replace&scope=quickref