# How I can get an img tag from string

Tags: php, regex, string

I have html string in variable in php. I want to get  tag from it. For example :

```
  $str ='<p><img src="link"></p><p>text</p>';
```

how can I get `<img src="link">` (or any `img` tag plus its content) from this string?

Comment: You want to check if a string has `<img>` tag in it or not?

Comment: `<img\b[^<>]*>` or `<img\s[^<>]*>`

Comment: you should first close your `img` tag

Comment: obligatory reference for parsing HTML with regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Pogrindis Not required, unless you're writing XHTML.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

User Regex in php. You should write regular expression for it

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

```
<img\s[^<>]*>
```

Comment: Maybe you should offer the regex expression also .. Just to have a complete answer. `<img\b[^<>]*>` or `<img\s[^<>]*>` As suggested by Avinash

Comment: The OP tagged this question with `regex`, this answer is telling the OP to use something they already thought they might need. What's the point?

Comment: OK guys, you are right. Should write the reg exp :)

Answer (score 3):

All answers seem a bit messy and include regex.

You dont need it.

```
$str ='<p><img src="link"></p><p>text</p>';
echo strip_tags($str, '<img>');
```

Will work nicely.

[Strip_tags Ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: did you try your code? Why it displays string `text` along with `img` tag? Because strip_tags  removes only the tags not it's contents.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use regular expressions, but you have to be careful to cater for any attributes that could be inside, or you can use the [DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) functionality along with [DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->loadHTML($str);

// gets all img tags in the string    
$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($imgs as $img) {    
    $img_strings[] = $doc->saveHTML($img);    
}
```

You then have all your img tags in the `$img_strings` variable.

In the `foreach` loop you can also get attributes within the tag:
`$img->getAttribute('src');`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do correctly:

I would suggest something like
[what is described here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/get-substring-between-two-strings-php)

They created a function to select the string contained between two particular strings. Here is their function:

```
function getInnerSubstring($string,$delim){
    // "foo a foo" becomes: array(""," a ","")
    $string = explode($delim, $string, 3); // also, we only need 2 items at most
    // we check whether the 2nd is set and return it, otherwise we return an empty string
    return isset($string[1]) ? $string[1] : '';
}
```

So long as there is not another set of `""` in your HTML then this should work for you.

If you use this you could search for what is only between those two `"`

Comment: If you are going to vote something down please leave an explanation or else nothing can be fixed to be more helpful

Comment: If you're going to post a link as an answer, try actually adding the relevant bit of information from that link in your answer. [Here's why it matters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: I didnt downvote this @Darksaint2014 but i would suggest offering some example to to OP

Comment: Thank you for giving feedback