# Strip Characters from PHP String

Tags: php, string

I have this string:

`An error page was displayed to the Web Services user.\nDetails: The Status you have chosen is invalid.\n\nStack Trace: Stack trace:`

The string itself actually goes on and on for about another ~1000 characters. What I want to do is extract what's between `Details:` and `\n\Stack`. I'd end up with `The Status you have chosen is invalid.`

I think I have the preceding character removal using `substr`:

```
<?php
$error = "An error page was displayed to the Web Services user.\nDetails: The Status you have chosen is invalid.\n\nStack Trace: Stack trace:.........";
$error2 = substr($error, 63);
echo $error2;
?>
```

But I always get an error `syntax error, unexpected end of file`. I figured out that it's the `\n` and `\n\` that are throwing that error, but I have no control over those as they are returned to my script from an external API call. I've only defined the `$error` here for illustrative purposes. This error is present even if I just echo `$error` not just `$error2`.

I've seen that I can do something like `$short = substr($str, 0, strpos( $str, ' - Name:'));` for the trailing character removal, but I need to get the preceding working before I can do that.

Any advice appreciated!

**Edit:** I mentioned this in a comment, but the error string gets passed to my script from the API by `$error = $e->getMessage();`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get substring between two strings PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/get-substring-between-two-strings-php)

Comment: If echoing the first string produces `\n`, you should wrap your `$error` test string in single quotes, to prevent the `\n` from being parsed into a newline character.

Comment: So in the actual working file, the error comes from `$error = $e->getMessage();` so I can't really wrap it in quotes since it doesn't originate written out like that. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @HoboSapiens No joy. `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '^'` Ran it as `$errora = preg_match("/^.*\sDetails:\s(.*)\sStack/m", $error);` (Edit: Saw your edit, same error)

Comment: `preg_match` is indeed what you want. Use http://www.regexr.com/ to figure out the exact regular expression to use with it. Also: don't put the regex in double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex with the `m` and `s` modifiers so that you can match newlines:

```
<?php
$error = "An error page was displayed to the Web Services user.\nDetails: The Status you have chosen is invalid.\n\nStack Trace: Stack trace:.........";

$result = preg_match("/^.*Details:\s(.*?)\n*Stack/ms", $error, $matches);
$errora = $matches[1];
echo $errora;
?>
```

Comment: That's perfect! Tested and working. Thanks a million!