# RegEx: Get the code between a BB [code] tag

Tags: php, regex, match

I'm trying to use PHP to do a search on strings inside `[code]` and `[php]` tags. However i cannot get that to work. Using the same regex on other BB tags I can successfully get a match but not on those tags.

I have this so far:

```
\[(?:code|php)\](.+?)\[\/(?:code|php)\]
```

This should match on the following content:

```
[code]
    this should be matched
[/code]

[php]
    this should be matched
[/php]
```

I'm using `preg_replace_callback` with an anonymous function but the function doesn't get called on those two tags. It get's called if I change the regex to match other tags but not those two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `.`, which matches all characters except newline. Switch it to a construct that also matches newlines, such as `[\s\S]`, or even use the flag `/s`:

```
\[(?:code|php)\]([\s\S]+?)\[\/(?:code|php)\]
```

```
~\[(?:code|php)\](.+?)\[\/(?:code|php)\]~s
```

Comment: Yeah. I just discovered that adding `/s` fixes the issue. I thought `/m` does the job but didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend matching `[code]` with `[/code]` and same with `[php]` and `[/php]`:

```
\[(code|php)\]([\s\S]+?)\[\/\1\]
```

In this case the actual code will be in match group 2. [See this Regex 101 for more information](https://regex101.com/r/fC3kJ3/1).

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to do regex. Consider:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

$fullstring = "this is my [tag]dog[/tag]";
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, "[tag]", "[/tag]");

echo $parsed; // (result = dog)
```

taken from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/get-substring-between-two-strings-php)

Comment: Even better seems. I'll look into it.