# Use PHP to extract HTML code between special tags into an array

Tags: php, html, html-content-extraction

Using the sample code below, I want to extract all code between each `<<BEGIN>>` and `<<END>>` tag and append the extracted code to an array for further processing later on.

```
<?php
$html = '<<BEGIN>><div>Some text goes here...</div><<END>><<BEGIN>><table border="0"><tr><td>Table cell text goes here</td></tr></table><<END>><<BEGIN>><ul><li>My string</li><li>Another string</li></ul><<END>>';
?>
```

The end result needs to look like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => '<div>Some text goes here...</div>'
    [1] => '<table border="0"><tr><td>Table cell text goes here</td></tr></table>'
    [2] => '<ul><li>My string</li><li>Another string</li></ul>'
)
```

Hope this makes sense.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: look into preg_match_all. you have some pretty basic rules, so the regex should be pretty easy to figure out. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Wouldn't using a database be easier?

Comment: I used this for all of my stuff http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/get-substring-between-two-strings-php

Comment: I would say you'll need to use a parser, as with a regex having only parent tags between each <<begin>> will require some heavy complex regex http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pretg_match_all() function to do this.

```
<?php

    $html = '<<BEGIN>><div>Some text goes here...</div><<END>><<BEGIN>><table border="0"><tr><td>Table cell text goes here</td></tr></table><<END>><<BEGIN>><ul><li>My string</li><li>Another string</li></ul><<END>>';

    preg_match_all("/<<BEGIN>>(.*)<<END>>/", $html, $result);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result[1]);
    echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Show the source code of the page and you will see all you wanted :) (, ...)

Comment: I did the full regex, and print_r the result he wanted. Don't forget to upvote if all is clear :)

Comment: You can check my answer in green to write that's resolute :)
You're welcome !

Answer (score 1):

You can strip the `<<END>>` and `<<BEGIN>>` from start and finish of the string and then explode on `<<END>><<BEGIN>>` .

```
$html = substr($html, 9);
$htmlleng = strlen($html) - 7;
$html = substr($html, 0, $htmlleng);
$myarray = explode('<<END>><<BEGIN>>', $html)
```

(You can make that more elegant but it shows what you would need to accomplish.)