# Recognising strings between certain tags in external file -PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am new to php, and want a script that can recognise text between certain tags in an external file.

I managed to find an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/get-substring-between-two-strings-php), that recognises the text in tags in a set string, but I am unsure of how to get the file to recognise the tags in an external text file.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
function innerh($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

$fullstring = "The <tag>Output</tag>"; // this is the string
$parsed = innerh($fullstring, "<tag>", "</tag>");

echo $parsed;
?>
```

**External File:**

```
<tag>This text</tag> <!-- This is the target -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to what you are already doing. Currently you are making a string with that tag and when you want to read it from a file you can simply do

```
$fullstring = file_get_contents('your-file.html');
```

No other changes are required. You might need to provide full path of that file but that's about it.

That function reads a file and returns its contents in a string which you can save in your variable just like you built the variable manually.

Comment: How would you be able to find multiple tags, then echo them?

Comment: You will have to take use of a better library than that basic function. SO has a ton of questions on that already a simple search will reveal. For example  `php parse html tags`

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be somthing like this:

```
<?php

function innerh($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

// Open a file with READ-ONLY flag ("r") and start of begining for read.
// See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
$fp = fopen("/path/to/file", "r");

// Check that file is opened and ready for read
if ($fp) {
    // Until we have content on file, we resume reading
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        // Read from file, line by line.
        // See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php
        $line = fgets($fp);

        // Process line by line and print result
        $parsed = innerh($line, "<tag>", "</tag>");
        echo $parsed;

        /* If your input file is a file without a new line or something like it,
           just add a `$line = '';` before while line and change read line with
           `$line  .= fgets($fp);`, also remove process line and print line. After
           that your file is on $line variable ;). */
    }
}
?>
```