# PHP get string between tag [Multiple tag in one string]

Tags: php, tags

I've been searching a lot but i cannot find anything similar to my problem. I've found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/get-substring-between-two-strings-php) but i don't think they really answered the question.

Let say i have this string

```
$my_string = "I am with a [id]123[/id] and [id]456[id]";
```

I want to get all the number between [id][/id]. I only have this function to get the string between.

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$fullstring = 'I am with a [id]123[/id] and [id]456[id]';
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, '[id]', '[/id]');
```

But this function only returns the first string found on $fullstring. Maybe i can get `123,456` or in array form array('123','456'). I really am stuck with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a substring between two strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/how-to-get-a-substring-between-two-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply use `preg_match_all` function of the PHP along with following regex

```
~\[id\](.*?)\[\/id\]~
```

like as

```
$my_string = "I am with a [id]123[/id] and [id]456[/id]";
preg_match_all("~\[id\](.*?)\[\/id\]~",$my_string,$m);
print_r($m[1]);
```