# Retrieving the top-level element with Regex

Tags: php, regex

I have the string bellow:

```
$string = '

@if(topLevel)
{{
  <form method="post">
    @if(bottomLevel)
    {{
      <input>
    }}
  </form>
}}';
```

What i'm trying is to find the value inside the @if(.*?) and the content between the brackets of the top level "@if".

This is the pattern i've tried:

```
@if\((.*?)\)(\s|\n|\t)+{{(\s|\n|\t)(.*?)(\s|\n|\t)}}
```

This is matching:

```
@if(bottomLevel)
{{
  <input>
}}
```

How can i go from the outside into the string and match the top level "@if"?

Comment: This is not a job for regex, you'd better use a parser.

Comment: How? can you give me some articles? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *singleline* flag, and remove lazy from `.*?`:

```
@if\((.*?)\)\s+{{\s*(.*)\s*}}
```

And since TAB is included in `\s`, and with the *singleline* flag `\n` as well, you only need `\s` to match the white space.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/r1CLtS/2).

**Edit**

Here's an alternative using recursion, to manage multiple groups of braces.

```
@if\((.*?)\)\s+{{((?:[^{}]|(?R))*)}}
```

[Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/r1CLtS/3).

Comment: This is exactly what i want: @if\((.*?)\)\s+{{((?:[^{}]|(?R))*)}}.

Answer (score 1):

`(.*?)` with the `?` is non-greedy matching, which means it will find the shortest possible match. Try without the `?`, and it won't stop at the first `}}`. You should also turn on the single-line flag `/s` and replace your whitespace pattern with simple `\s*`.

Result: `/@if\((.*?)\)\s*\{\{\s*(.*)\s*\}\}/s`

PS.: I escaped `{}` characters, which is not necessary for your case, but I like to escape characters that have a meaning in regex.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I hate preg_matches, so I did with [substr](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php) and [substr-count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php), I love the readability of that:

```
    $string = '

@if(topLevel)
{{
  <form method="post">
    @if(mediumLevel)
    {{
      <input>
    }}
  </form>
  <form method="post">
    @if(bottomLevel)
    {{
      <input>
    }}
  </form>
}}';
function string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $total = substr_count($string, $start);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++){
        $string = ' ' . $string;
        $ini = strpos($string, $start);
        $ini += strlen($start);
        $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
        $result[$i] = substr($string, $ini, $len);
        $string = substr($string, $len);
        $ini = strpos($string, $start);
        $string = substr($string, $ini);
    }
    return $result;
}

function string_between_brackets($string, $start, $end){
    $total = substr_count($string, $start);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++){
        $string = ' ' . $string;
        $ini = strpos($string, $start);
        $ini += strlen($start);
        if ($i == 0){
            $len = strrpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
        } else {
            $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
        }
        $result[$i] = substr($string, $ini, $len);
        $string = substr($string, $ini);
    }
    return $result;
}

$parsed = string_between($string, '@if(', ')');
$parsedContent = string_between_brackets($string, '{{', '}}');
$i = 0;
$parsedString = array_combine($parsed, $parsedContent);
var_dump($parsedString);

/*array (size=3)
  'topLevel' => string '
  <form method="post">
    @if(mediumLevel)
    {{
      <input>
    }}
  </form>
  <form method="post">
    @if(bottomLevel)
    {{
      <input>
    }}
  </form>
' (length=165)
  'mediumLevel' => string '
      <input>
    ' (length=19)
  'bottomLevel' => string '
      <input>
    ' (length=19)*/
```

Inspired by [Get substring between two strings PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/get-substring-between-two-strings-php)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that's not what i want. What i'm trying is to find the value inside the @if(.*?) !!!!!and!!!!! the content between the brackets of the top level "@if".

Comment: Can you test now?

Comment: This works! But it's not a good solution since i'm talking about Regex.

Comment: That's ok, I just wanted to show other perspective. Thx.

Comment: I guess the Regex approach is more fast

Comment: But i'm learning with it, i never saw the substr_count before, thanks.

Comment: And more readable too, I liked @ClasG solution. Just wanted to improve my skills trying other point of view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think regex is the best way to parse your code, anyway here is a suggestion getting the part of the code you want in two times:

#### Regex 1: extracts the parameter in @if(...)

```
@if\((\w+)\)
```

It extracts from your string:

```
topLevel
bottomLevel
```

[**Test it on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/ptYfA5/4)

---

#### Regex 2: get the value between brackets

```
{{\s+([<\w\s"@(){}\/=>]+)}}
```

It extracts from your string:

```
<form method="post">
  @if(bottomLevel)
  {{
    <input>
  }}
</form>
```

[**Test it on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/ptYfA5/6)

Comment: That's not what i want, this only give me the content inside the parentheses of @if, i want a regex that match the top level and give me the content between it's brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

`{{\n\s+(.+)\n.+}}`

It looks for opening double curly braces, then a new line, then any number of characters, followed by a new line, some spaces, any characters followed by a new line, any chars, and then the closing }}. The brackets capture the specific text.

You can see an example of it here: https://regex101.com/r/pwFNA1/1

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that's not what i want. What i'm trying is to find the value inside the @if(.*?) !!!!!and!!!!! the content between the brackets of the top level "@if".

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic regex that supports bracket multiple-nesting:

```
@if\((.*?)\)\s+({{\s+((?:[^{}]|(?2))*?)\s+}})
```

Capturing groups are `$1` and `$3`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ENQ6l2/1).

Anyway, I've got some generic hints:

- `\t` and `\n` are redundant with respect to `\s`. Don't use `(\t|\n|\s)+`, use just `\s+`.
- You cannot match multiple lines using `.*`, you need to use the *singleline* modifier.