# PHP explode string with tags using UTF8 between them

Tags: php

in php i want to explode string with tag using utf-8 between them, for example, in this text:

```
$content = "<heading>فهرست اول</heading>hi my name is mahdi  whats app <heading>فهرست دوم</heading>how are you";
```

in that i have to `<heading></heading>` tag with utf8 between them, i want to have simple array with them like with:

```
$arr[0] = "<heading>فهرست اول</heading>hi my name is mahdi  whats app";
$arr[1] = "<heading>فهرست دوم</heading>how are you";
```

strings between `<heading></heading>` are different, how can i make this array? question is how can i explode text by `<heading>ENY TEXT</heading>`

Comment: Heave you tried using regex? `preg_split` with  `/(?=<heading>.*?<\/heading>)/`  as pattern should work...

Comment: It should answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/get-substring-between-two-strings-php

Comment: @Soaku no, could you help me how can i use this reqular?

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy `$arr = preg_split('/(?=<heading>.*?<\/heading>)/', $content)` will split the string on the `<heading>` tag, no matter of its contents without removing it. This should work...

Comment: @Soaku yes, that work fine, but i want to have between tag with parent, i dont like to remove `heading`

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy I posted it as an answer, so I can explain it better,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_split` to split the text by a regular expression, then `array_filter` to remove empty strings:

```php
$arr = array_filter(preg_split('/(?=<heading>.*?<\/heading>)/', $contents), 'strlen');
```

It won't remove the  tag, since it is in a `look-ahead` - a group construct that doesn't consume what it matched.

For example:

```
<heading>فهرست اول</heading>hi my name is mahdi  whats app <heading>فهرست دوم</heading>how are you
```

This should return:

```
array(
  [0] => "<heading>فهرست اول</heading>hi my name is mahdi  whats app ",
  [1] => "<heading>فهرست دوم</heading>how are you"
)
```

You can check this regex online: https://regex101.com/r/ITi7Lh/1
Or, if you prefer, see how PHP parses it: (the link doesn't seem to work on SO, you have to manually paste it): `https://en.functions-online.com/preg_split.html?command={"pattern":"\/(?=<heading>.*?<\\\/heading>)\/","subject":"<heading>\u0641\u0647\u0631\u0633\u062a \u0627\u0648\u0644<\/heading>hi my name is mahdi whats app <heading>\u0641\u0647\u0631\u0633\u062a \u062f\u0648\u0645<\/heading>how are you","limit":-1}`

Comment: i'm sorry sir, i have this result with you code: `Array
(
    [1] => فهرست اولhi my name is mahdi  whats app 
    [2] => فهرست دومhow are you
)
`

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy Impossible. I'm getting the correct result... I'm editing the answer to include a link to preg_split tester

Comment: i pasted url on other tab of FF, but i get this error `Your connection is not secure` i'm wondering why this code dont work correctly for me and cause of remove `heading` tags

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy Are you sure you pasted everything as I written?

Comment: yes sure, i use this code: `$arr = array_filter(
    preg_split('/(?=<heading>.*?<\/heading>)/', $request->input('post')),
    'strlen');`

Comment: I'm so sorry sir, you have right, after see source page i know result is correct

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy I was about to say this, but IDK why I didn't post that. Good to know that it helped. :)

Comment: i have another question for this topic, how can i replace all `<heading> title1 </heading>` to `title1`? Thanks

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy if you don't use any other tag, `strip_tags` will remove html notation without removing contents. Otherwise, you could use some regex like... `/<\/?heading.*?>/

Comment: thanks, `preg_replace('/<\/?heading>/', ' ', $contents);` resolve my problem

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy I'm happy to help :) Just wanted to note, that even when regex might be simple, but they aren't always the best solution. If you use complex regexes or just too often, you might notice a slow down. If an alternative exists - use it. Other people here already offered some, so they might be better for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use strpos and Substr to do the same if your UTF is causing issues.

This will loop till it can't find anymore heading and then add the last Substr after the loop.

https://3v4l.org/UPfbb

```
$content = "<heading>فهرست اول</heading>hi my name is mahdi  whats app <heading>فهرست دوم</heading>how are you<heading>فهرست اول</heading>hi my name is mahdi  whats app2 <heading>فهرست دوم</heading>how are you2";

$oldpos =0;
$pos =strpos($content, "<heading>",1); // offset 1 to exclude first heading.

While($pos !== false){
    $arr[] = Substr($content, $oldpos, $pos-$oldpos);
    $oldpos = $pos;
    $pos =strpos($content, "<heading>",$oldpos+1); //offset previous position + 1 to make sure it does not catch the same again 
}
$arr[] = Substr($content, $oldpos); // add last one since it does not have a heading tag after itself.
Var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_match`, or in your case, `preg_match_all`:

```
$content = "<heading>فهرست اول</heading>hi my name is mahdi  whats app <heading>فهرست دوم</heading>how are you";

preg_match_all("'<heading>.*?<\/heading>'si", $content, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <heading>فهرست اول</heading>
    [1] => <heading>فهرست دوم</heading>
)
```

Comment: He expects to get also what's behind the tag until the next one. Not only what's inside it

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following function, it should meet your needs well. Basically you should split the array using `<heading>` as the delimiter, and each item in the resultant array will be what you require, but the heading tag will be stripped since it is what you did your split on, so you need to add it back. There are comments explaining what the code is doing.

```
function get_what_mahdi_wants($in_string){

  $mahdis_strings_array = array();

  // Split string at occurrences of '<heading>'
  $mahdis_strings = explode('<heading>', $in_string);
  foreach($mahdis_strings as $mahdis_string){

    // if '<heading>' is found at start of string, empty array element will be created. Skip it.
    if($mahdis_string == ''){ continue; }

    // Add back string element with '<heading>' tag prepended since exploding on it stripped it.
    $mahdis_strings_array[] = '<heading>'.$mahdis_string;
  }
  return $mahdis_strings_array;
}
```