# PHP using itrator solution to find all tags match

Tags: php, regex

You suppose i have this string:

```
$text= "11111111<mft:A>2222222</mft:A>1111111<mft:S>33333333</mft:S> 
        <mft:A>99999</mft:A><mft:S>v44444444/mft:S><mft:R>555555</mft:R>
        <mft:S>6666666</mft:S><mft:A>7777777</mft:A>111111";
```

i'm trying to find all texts are between this tag `<mft:A>` and `</mft:A>`

i know whats solution of this action on java but i don't know how can i implementing that on `PHP` and what's equvalent, for example:

```
String text= "11111111<mft:A>2222222</mft:A>1111111<mft:S>33333333</mft:S> 
        <mft:A>99999</mft:A><mft:S>v44444444/mft:S><mft:R>555555</mft:R>
        <mft:S>6666666</mft:S><mft:A>7777777</mft:A>111111";

Pattern mftA_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<mft:A>(.+?)</mft:A>");
Matcher matcher = mftA_REGEX.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String found = matcher.group(1);
}
```

Comment: Check out [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for regex matching.

Comment: @revo and you are using a language that is not accepted on SO. And for no reason since OP seems to get along quite fine in English. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content

Comment: @revo informing about rules is not "picking".

Comment: @revo could you help me on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46282343/1830228)?

Comment: @revo in that case I think you should flag or post on meta.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not a good flagger like you. Let's put an end to it. @Andreas

Comment: @revo I haven't flagged anything. Feel free to apologise

Comment: @Andreas instead of talking about unnecessary flags, please help me on this topic https://stackoverflow.com/q/46282343/1830228

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with this regex:

```
preg_match_all("/<mft:A>(.+?)<\/mft:A>/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

OR

```
preg_match("/<mft:A>(.+?)<\/mft:A>/", $input_line, $output_array);
```