# Without Regex: String Between Quotes?

Tags: php, string

I'm creating a word-replacement script. I've run into a roadblock with ignoring strings between quotes and haven't been able to find a decent solution here that didn't involve Regex.

I have a working snippet that cycles through every character in the string and figures out whether the most recent quotation was an opening or closing quote (Whether single or double) and ignores escaped quotes. The problem is that in order for it to provide a 100% accurate experience, it has to run every time the string changes (Because of how it works, it could change well over 60K times across a single function), and due to string length potential, the code takes too long even on a fairly short script.

Is there a fast way to figure out whether a string is between open and close quotes (Single and double)? Ignoring escaped " and '. Or, do you have suggestions on how to optimize the snippet to make it run significantly faster? Removing this function, the process runs at almost the preferred speed (Instant).

As an exercise, consider copying and pasting the snippet into the script with a variable containing text. For example $thisIsAQuote = "This is a quote."; And, from that point, everything should replace correctly, except $thisIsAQuote should retain its exact text.

But here's the issue: Other solutions I've found will treat everything between "This is a quote." and ... $this->formatted[$i - 1] != " ... as if it's still between quotes. Because as far as those solutions are concerned, the last quote in "This is a quote." and the first quote in the if-check are open and close quotes. Another obvious issue is that some strings contain words with apostrophes. Apostrophes shouldn't be treated as single-quotes, but in all solutions I've found, they are.

In other words, they're "unaware" solutions.

```
    $quoteClosed = true;
    $singleQuoteClosed = true;

    $codeLength = mb_strlen($this->formatted);
    if ($codeLength == false)
        return;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $codeLength; $i++)
    {
        if ((!$quoteClosed || !$singleQuoteClosed) && ($this->formatted[$i] == '"' || $this->formatted[$i] == "'"))
        {
            if (!$quoteClosed && $this->formatted[$i - 1] != "\\")
                $quoteClosed = true;
            else if (!$singleQuoteClosed && $this->formatted[$i - 1] != "\\")
                $singleQuoteClosed = true;
        }
        else if ($this->formatted[$i] == '"' && ($i <= 0 || $this->formatted[$i - 1] != "\\"))
        {
            if ($quoteClosed && $singleQuoteClosed)
                $quoteClosed = false;
        }
        else if ($this->formatted[$i] == "'" && ($i <= 0 || $this->formatted[$i - 1] != "\\"))
        {
            if ($singleQuoteClosed && $quoteClosed)
                $singleQuoteClosed = false;
        }

        if ($quoteClosed && $singleQuoteClosed)
            $this->quoted[$i] = 0;
        else
            $this->quoted[$i] = 1;
    }
```

If there isn't a way to make the above more efficient, is there a non-Regex way to quickly replace all substrings in an array with substrings in a second array without missing any across an entire string?

substr_replace and str_replace only seem to replace "some" pieces of the overall string, which is why the number of iterations are in place. It cycles through a while loop until either strpos deems a string nonexistent (Which it never seems to do ... I may be using it wrong), or it cycles through 10K times, whichever occurs first.

Running the above snippet -once- per round would solve the speed issue, but that leaves the "full-replacement" issue and, of course, staying aware that it should avoid replacing anything within quotes.

```
    for ($a = 0; $a < count($this->keys); $a++)
    {
        $escape = 0;
        if ($a > count($this->keys) - 5)
            $this->formatted = $this->decodeHTML($this->formatted);

        while (strpos($this->formatted, $this->keys[$a]) !== false)
        {
            $valid = strpos($this->formatted, $this->keys[$a]);
            if ($valid === false || $this->quoted[$valid] === 1)
                break;

            $this->formatted = substr_replace($this->formatted, $this->answers[$a], $valid, mb_strlen($this->keys[$a]));
            $this->initializeQuoted();
            $escape++;

            if ($escape >= 10000)
                break;
        }

        if ($a > count($this->keys) - 5)
            $this->formatted = html_entity_decode($this->formatted);
    }
    $this->quoted = array();
    $this->initializeQuoted();
    return $this->formatted;
```

'keys' and 'answers' are arrays containing words of various lengths. 'formatted' is the new string with the changed information. 'initializeQuoted' is the above snippet. I use htmlentities and html_entity_decode to help get rid of whitespaces with key/answer replacements.

Ignore the magic numbers (5s and 10K).

Comment: Have you thought of just debouncing calls to the function first? Maybe that will be good enough.

Comment: Do you mean running the function prior to the while loop? I've done that, but it results in heavy inaccuracies (A lot of missed changes) because the while loop is what performs the changes and the quote-tracker is no longer up to date when a single change is made, let alone several. Running the function after the while loop each time has the exact same problem, naturally.

Comment: _"Apostrophes shouldn't be treated as single-quotes, but in all solutions I've found, they are."_ - that's probably because of the _complexity_ of that requirement, despite that you are simply throwing it out there in a nonchalant "oh an I also need this, but that should be no biggie" fashion. `The title of the book was 'All of Hans' favorite Poems', if I remember correctly.` - now you tell me what script logic you expect to figure out which one is the correct closing single quote? That needs understanding of _human language_, so you are getting close to AI capabilities here.

Comment: No, debouncing refers to spacing out the function calls so there is a minimum time between calls. So you don't call it at every change.

Comment: Eh. Given IDEs have had the capability for over two decades, I think you're giving the 'complexity' issue too much attention, @Cbroe. If it's simply not in PHP's built-in logic, it's an oversight or a "not-popular-enough-of-a-request," not an AI-specialty problem to be solved. It's been solved for a long time. Whether it's been -simplified- is the question. In your exact example, it takes more effort, but keep in mind that apostrophes can be escaped mid-sentence. So that exact example doesn't qualify. What I mean: "All of Hans' favorite Poems" shouldn't look at the apostrophe.

Comment: @RayToal Haven't done that, going to have to figure out how to approach it while getting flawless results and desired speed. Nothing you can see offhand in either snippet that would increase speed or make either more efficient? ... Actually, thanks for that suggestion, 'cause I might be able to fix this issue based on that. But if you can think of fixes, let me know.

Comment: _"but keep in mind that apostrophes can be escaped mid-sentence"_ - yes, but you did not specify that they _need_ to be. And neither other conditions that would limit the complexity, such as different decision making based whether white space, certain punctuation, or letters follow after, etc. If you can rely on that your input data will follow some more or less basic typographic conventions, then the complexity might be limited, but if you have to work on all possible kinds of input, I rather doubt that the task is as simple as you imagine.

Comment: @CBroe Doubt all you like. I've written the logic a few dozen times in C++. PHP simply doesn't have the same functions (Or I don't know the syntax for said functions -- And it's been a long time). It's not complex given the right tools, like any other problem.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have an easily accessible demo version of that laying around somewhere, would love to see how that performs on various example inputs ...

Comment: I haven't read all your question it was just massive. But you can have a look at this answer I made a while ago about looping through a string with strpos. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282343/php-explode-string-with-tags-using-utf8-between-them/46284684#46284684

Comment: Like I said, been a long time. Given it was used by around 400 people as a dedicated word processor -- among other things -- it did what it needed to do once I got through the kinks. Yes, it requires thought, debugging, and testing. But go test any IDE on the planet, which is built on the same technologies we have access to, and you'll find they have the functionality being described here. Ignoring single-quotes within double-quote strings and identifying strings amongst a variety of other text is neither "new" nor "impossible."

Comment: @Andreas When I'm not detailed, I get people like CBroe or I get downvoted. Got 'em anyway. :P Either way, thanks for that, but I realized a little bit ago (In part thanks to @RayToal) why this isn't breaking out of the loop. When it finds something inside a quote and decides to skip it, it treats it as if it's still there. In other words, it doesn't realize I'm intentionally skipping it, so it knows there's something still in existence. That'd be why it's so slow. I also found a way to only have to call the function once I think. Did take a look at the answer, so we'll see if I can mix-solve.

Comment: There's too much noise in this question. I'm sure you can trim down a lot of it and focus more on what you need to do. For example consider providing something like: "If I get input X I need to return Y" for a few example cases

Comment: @apokryfos Generally when I ask a straightforward question without details like "how can I get a self-aware IDE-like string-collector," I get pointed to 15 different posts that don't solve the issue, a dozen downvotes, and a "duplicate" tag. SO's not a friendly place either way. At least this way the people who'd usually do all of the above are less likely to because "TL; DR." If SO was less trigger-happy in an e-pen way, I could shrink it. As it sits, the questions speak for themselves: Efficiency and specific requirements with snippets of current attempts. The 'example case' is in there too.

Comment: As an asker you have the task of educating anyone who reads the question as to what it is exactly you need the code to do. Right now I have no clue.

Comment: The script needs to be able to figure out what text is within an open and close quotation, whether single or double-quotes. Needs to ignore apostrophes in a situation where double-quotes are surrounding them. Needs to be able to replace one word with another word (Key vs. Answer), -unless- the word is within quotations. And must do all of the above as quickly as possible. Current functions work, but are far too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then you can do this:

```
$replacements = [
    "test" => "banana",
    "Test" => "Banana"
];  

$brackets = [[0]];
$lastOpenedQuote = null;



for ($i = 0;$i < strlen($string);$i++) {

    if ($string[$i] == "\\") { $i++; continue; } //Skip escaped chars

    if ($string[$i] == $lastOpenedQuote) {
        $lastOpenedQuote = null;
        $brackets[count($brackets)-1][] = $i; 
        $brackets[] = [ $i+1 ];
    } elseif ($lastOpenedQuote == null && ($string[$i] == "\"" || $string[$i] == "'")) {
        $lastOpenedQuote = $string[$i];
        $brackets[count($brackets)-1][] = $i-1; 
        $brackets[] = [ $i ];
    }
}
$brackets[count($brackets)-1][] = strlen($string)-1;

$prev = 0;
$bits = [];
foreach ($brackets as $index => $pair) {
    $bits[$index] = substr($string,$pair[0],$pair[1]-$pair[0]+1);
    if ($bits[$index][0] != "\"" && $bits[$index][0] != "'") {
        $bits[$index] = str_replace(array_keys($replacements),array_values($replacements), $bits[$index]);
    }
}
```

Check it out at: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0453cb7941f1dcad636043fceff30dc0965541ee

Now if performance is still an issue keep in mind this goes through each string character 1 time and does the minimum number of checks it needs each time so it will be really hard to reduce it more. Perhaps you should revise your approach from the bottom up if you need something faster like e.g. doing some of the splitting on the client-side progressively instead of on the whole string on the serverside.

Comment: Huh. I'll have to dissect it, but looking at the sandbox, looks like that'll work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was just working on this. Hope this gives you some additional ideas.

```
MATCH: ["]([\w\s\(\)\.\d\_\-\[\]\{\}]+|\s*)["]

REPLACE: ""

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NotepadPlus>
    <ScintillaContextMenu>
        <!--
        NOTES: BLAH
        -->
        [WEBSITE]
        https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/blob/master/PowerEditor/installer/nativeLang/english.xml
            -->
        <Item MenuId="Tools" MenuItemName="Generate..."/>
        <Item MenuEntryName="Edit" FolderName="Remove Lines" MenuItemName="Remove Empty Lines" ItemNameAs="Empty Lines"/>
        <Item MenuEntryName="Plugins" FolderName="Remove Lines" MenuItemName="Remove duplicate lines" ItemNameAs="Duplicate Lines (Plugin)"/>
        <Item MenuEntryName="Edit" FolderName="Remove Lines" MenuItemName="Remove Consecutive Duplicate Lines" ItemNameAs="Duplicate Lines"/>
        <Item MenuEntryName="Search" FolderName="Add Style Tokens" MenuItemName="Using 1st Style" ItemNameAs="1"/>
        <Item id="45003" Foldername="Convert" ItemNameAs="Macintosh (CR)"/>
        <Item id="0" FolderName="XML Tools"/>
        <Item MenuEntryName="Plugins" FolderName="XML Tools" MenuItemName="Options..." ItemNameAs="Options"/>

    </ScintillaContextMenu>
</NotepadPlus>
```

Let me know if you come up with anything else.