# get number between two string by using substring

Tags: mysql, sql

I m trying to get number in between "sims_7009_alaira", i want 7009.

```
SELECT sno,dbase, SUBSTRING_INDEX(dbase, 'sims_', -1)temp
FROM school
```

How should i do that in SQL

Comment: By using substring i got 7009_alaira but i only want 7009

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a substring between two strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/how-to-get-a-substring-between-two-strings-in-php)

Comment: How is SQL related in any way to PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
select substring_index(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dbase, '_', 2),'_',-1) from school;
```

Check this here:
[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f03ac/1)

Answer (score 0):

Just use substring_index() two times:

SELECT sno, dbase, substring_index(substring_index(dbase, 'sims_', -1), '_alaira', 1) as number FROM school

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
SELECT sno,dbase, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dbase, "_", 2),'_',-1) temp
FROM school;
```

For more insight see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring_index.asp).