# how can I get an array of substring between specific characters?

Tags: php, string, function, substring, php-7

I have this string

```
$names = "The names are: [Yossi] & [Jane] & [Mono] & [Kiko]"
```

and I want my input to be:

```
array / list => [Yossi, Jane, Mono, Kiko]
```

I tried using some function from here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/how-to-get-a-substring-between-two-strings-in-php)

But all I got was Yossi.

I understand the reasone that all I see from those functions is "Yossi" but I couldn't figure out I can I get the rest of the names in some sort of an array or some kind of a list.

Thanks!

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression `/\[[a-zA-Z]*\]/`

```
preg_match_all('/\[[a-zA-Z]*\]/', $names, $matches);
```

your substrings will be saved in `$matches[0]`

See PHP Docs for [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Comment: A super-useful tool that I love is regex101.com - [Here is this Regular Expression in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IvfCtr/1) so you can see exactly how that regex is processed....

Answer (score 0):

```
$names="The names are: [Yossi] & [Jane] & [Mono] & [Kiko]";
$clean1=explode(': ', $names);
$clean2=str_replace("] & ["," ",$clean1[1]);
$result=explode(" ", $clean2);
```

Comment: Kudos for resourcefulness, but regex really is the right way to go here.  This way is too brittle, and relies on some specific things that might break if the string were slightly different.

Comment: agreed regex is the simpler way to do it :-) upvoted your answer