# Modify only a specific string that is part of a larger string

Tags: php, laravel, google-calendar-api, str-replace

How can I edit or delete data in google calendar event description?

I'm using Laravel with Google Calendar (i.e., a spatie package). When I update an event description, it overwrites the entire content, but I only need to change a part of the data.

I currently get the data from a form and add it to a variable like this:

```
$variable = [
"Name: " . $name . "<br/>" .
"Product: " . $product . "<br/>
];

$event->description = $variable;
$event->save();
```

After I save it in the Google Calendar, I would like to change only "Name", for example, is it possible?

Comment: Can you share proper code? If you concatenate some big string, how do you want to change data within?

Comment: thanks for reply. the google calendar $event->description, only accepts strings.I need to change some data from this string after it was written to the calendar and I was not finding a "smart" solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, all you are doing is saving a string. 
If that is indeed the case, a possiblity would be that:

- next time when you retrieve the string to parse it and use `Name:` and `<br\>` as delimiters
- then you can perform a substring replacement for the string in between your delimiters

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9826656/5252007) shows you an implementation for how to achieve this using `php`. Also, take a look at [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), but keep in mind that it replaces *all* occurrences.