# How to get substring between two strings in DART?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i achieve similar solution to: [How to get a substring between two strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/how-to-get-a-substring-between-two-strings-in-php) but in DART

For example I have a String:
`String data = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"`
I have two other Strings: `quick` and `over`
I want the `data` inside these two Strings and expecting result:
`brown fox jumps`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use `String.indexOf` combined with `String.substring`:

```dart
void main() {
  const str = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
  const start = "quick";
  const end = "over";

  final startIndex = str.indexOf(start);
  final endIndex = str.indexOf(end, startIndex + start.length);

  print(str.substring(startIndex + start.length, endIndex)); // brown fox jumps
}
```

Note also that the `startIndex` is *inclusive*, while the `endIndex` is *exclusive*.

Comment: I was almost about to post an answer with `RegExp`. But this one's better

Comment: My String is actually unformatted `HTML` and is very long. `substring` method 
 failed with RangeError. So, @Sergey Solodukhin's answer worked for me.
This one is awesome for smaller Strings. Thank you.

Comment: @SukhchainSingh it was a bug. I've just fixed it

Comment: @RémiRousselet Thank you, it worked. It's lot faster than regexp as expected :)

Comment: What's about real data? Word order may change "the over quick brown fox jumps the lazy dog" or one keyword may be absent.

Comment: @SergeySolodukhin No it's not absent in my case and order will be not changed too.

Answer (score 10):

I love regexp with lookbehind `(?<...)` and lookahead `(?=...)`:

```
void main() {
  var re = RegExp(r'(?<=quick)(.*)(?=over)');
  String data = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
  var match = re.firstMatch(data);
  if (match != null) print(match.group(0));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, my string was very large so [Rémi Rousselet's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57186482/7814638) answer didn't helped. This one worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

```
final str = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
final start = 'quick';
final end = 'over';

final startIndex = str.indexOf(start);
final endIndex = str.indexOf(end);
final result = str.substring(startIndex + start.length, endIndex).trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

For future researchers:
To start form the beginning of a string to a specific symbol or character;

Using substring and indexOf which is faster than regExp do this:

```
void main() {
  const str = "Cars/Horses";

  final endIndex = str.indexOf("/", 0);

  print(str.substring(0, endIndex)); // Cars
}
```

**This might just help someone**

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the help of regex.
Create a function that will return the regex matches as

```
Iterable<String> _allStringMatches(String text, RegExp regExp) => 
regExp.allMatches(text).map((m) => m.group(0));
```

And then define your regex as `RegExp(r"[quick ]{1}.*[ over]{1}"))`

Answer (score 0):

The substring functionality isn't that great, and will throw errors for strings above the "end" value.

To make it simpler user this custom function that doesn't thrown an error, instead using the max length.

```
String substring(String original, {required int start, int? end}) {
  if (end == null) {
    return original.substring(start);
  }
  if (original.length < end) {
    return original.substring(start, original.length);
  }
  return original.substring(start, end);
}
```