# How to select string from database where start and end with ul

Tags: php, mysql, substring

Is it possible to select part of a text from within a DB where the string starts with UL and finish with /UL ?

In the database product description there is a record in a text column with html special characters like this

```
ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Upper line&amp;nbsp;:&amp;nbsp;2650/300/720&lt;br&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Down line :&amp;nbsp;2050/600/900&amp;nbsp;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Height :&amp;nbsp;480mm&lt;br&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;
```

But there is more text and html around this `ul`:

```
&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Size:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 20px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Upper line&amp;nbsp;:&amp;nbsp;2650/300/720&lt;br&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Down line :&amp;nbsp;2050/600/900&amp;nbsp;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Height :&amp;nbsp;480mm&lt;br&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;
```

Is there any way to select/extract only the part from text that starts and ends with `ul` ?

Comment: Why is the data HTML encoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring_index.asp) and [SUBSTRING](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring.asp).

But personally, I would prefer extracting the substring in PHP.
Example of code using PHP:

```
function get_substring($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
$fullstring = 'Words words words <ul> you are awesome </ul>';
$myString = get_substring($fullstring, '<ul>', '</ul>');

echo $myString;
```

I would recommend you to check this answer for more code samples: [How to get a substring between two strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/how-to-get-a-substring-between-two-strings-in-php)

Comment: can you give me any example of doing it with php?

Comment: I've edited the original answer and included a piece of PHP code